# Looking for an email or contact for the Sound Collectors Club

Tags: sfx

Just as the title says.  I am trying to find out some additional information about the Sound Collectors Club, but on the website there is not a single point of contact listed that I could find.

The main thing I want to know is if I join and contribute to the current theme, I know I then get access to that theme.  Am I able to get access to previous/older themes by contributing to those after the fact?

Answer (score 2):

Based on their [About page](http://thesoundcollectorsclub.com/about/how-to-upload-your-sounds-to-the-club/):

> Just copy the file(s) into that folder then I’ll check your recording
>   and move it to the appropriate theme folder (e.g. ‘Dog Barks’) then
>   I’ll invite you to join that folder.  When you accept, the entire ‘Dog
>   Barks’ folder will sync to your Google Drive – the more themes you
>   contribute to, the bigger collection of folders you get on your
>   desktop.

It appears that you can contribute to any category you want and then get access to that category.

He also points out his contact information there:

> I’m pretty sure that this is a watertight description of what to do
>   but if you’re having any issues please feel free to contact me at
>   michael@thesoundcollectorsclub.com and I’ll guide you through it.

Comment: Thank you,  I thought I looked all over for a contact, but missed it.